# Python script has a syntax error with triple quoted string on remote server. What is going on?

Tags: python-3.x, ssh

I have this bit of code that will not execute on a remote server when I run the script on it using ssh.

```
build_query(self):
        return f'''
            SELECT d.name AS domain,
            u.value AS uuid,
            e.value AS email,
            sf.sf_id AS salesforce_lead_id
            FROM form_submissions fs
            LEFT JOIN form_categorizations fc
            ON fs.id = fc.form_submission_id
            LEFT JOIN degree_offerings d
            ON d.id = fc.degree_offering_id
            LEFT JOIN emails e
            ON e.id = fs.email_id
            LEFT JOIN uuids u
            ON u.prospect_id = e.prospect_id
            LEFT JOIN sf_leads sf
            ON e.prospect_id = sf.prospect_id AND d.id = sf.degree_offering_id
            WHERE u.is_primary = 1 AND fs.prospect_id IN (%s)
        '''
```

and I'm running this bash command:

cat ~/script.py | ssh bastion.prod.data.com python3 -
  File "", line 66
    WHERE u.is_primary = 1 AND fs.prospect_id IN (%s)'''
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

It runs locally fine. What is going on?

Comment: That's not the entire input; the error message says line 66. The source of the error is earlier in the file.

Comment: f-strings are relatively new so that remote Python might not recognize it. Which brings us to: why make this an f-string?

Comment: It was an f string problem. server was running python 3.4

Comment: It's for the interpolation at the end

Answer (score 0):

I have just realized you posted the solution in the comments section @Jwan622, but I'll add it here to help other people.

f-strings are only supported on python 3.6 or greater. I had the same issue working with Python 3.5.

A workaround would be to use the .format() method.

```
'SELECT d.name AS domain,
        u.value AS uuid,
        e.value AS email,
        sf.sf_id AS salesforce_lead_id
        FROM form_submissions fs
        LEFT JOIN form_categorizations fc
        ON fs.id = fc.form_submission_id
        LEFT JOIN degree_offerings d
        ON d.id = fc.degree_offering_id
        LEFT JOIN emails e
        ON e.id = fs.email_id
        LEFT JOIN uuids u
        ON u.prospect_id = e.prospect_id
        LEFT JOIN sf_leads sf
        ON e.prospect_id = sf.prospect_id AND d.id = sf.degree_offering_id
        WHERE u.is_primary = 1 AND fs.prospect_id IN ({})'.format(your_list_here)
```

https://blog.softhints.com/python-3-syntaxerror-invalid-syntax-f-strings/